# can we use single cursor multiple time without opening it again?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have 2 cursors in mysql, the second cursor should run with every first cursor iteration without opening it again. Any idea? Thanks in advance
for ex:-

```
DECLARE email_not_found INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET email_not_found = 1; 
open cur1;
open cur2;

REPEAT
FETCH cur1 INTO s1;

REPEAT
   FETCH cur2 INTO s2;

   if s1=s2
      do something.

UNTIL email_not_found=1 END REPEAT;

UNTIL email_not_found=1 END REPEAT; 
close cur1;
close cur2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the cursor every time. According to MySQL cursor documentation, cursor are readonly and Nonscrollable: Can be traversed only in one direction and cannot skip rows

Due to this reason, you cannot rewind it and you need to open cursor in your loop.

Comment: As the data in cursor is huge i don't want to open several time instead use it several time. After reaching at the end of the cursor can we reset the cursor back to beginning?

Comment: MySQL Cursor are non scrollable, so you can only move forward with it. Alternative is, try to replace your two nested cursor with JOINS, but I am not sure whether it is feasible or not without looking into queries for two cursors

Comment: To avoid joins directly on the tables i am using cursors. Because there are lakhs of data for one day and i thought it would be easy to take whole data at once in cursor than joins and groups which internally sorts many time and it costs more. THANK YOU

Comment: Cursor does not store the whole data, when you fetch from cursor, only data of row pointed by cursor will be returned